# Elasticsearch - Order by input options

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have an index with the following data:

```
{  
  "_index":"businesses",
  "_type":"business",
  "_id":"1",
  "_version":1,
  "found":true,
  "_source":{  
    "business":{  
      "account_level_id":"2",
      "business_city":"Abington",
      "business_country":"United States of America",
    }
  }
}
```

When I query the index, I want to sort by account_level_id (which is a digit between 1-5). The problem is, I don't want to sort in ASC or DESC order, but by the following: 4..3..5..2..1. This was caused by bad practice a couple years ago, where the account level maxed out at level 4, but then a lower level account was added with the value of 5. Is there a way to tell ES that I want the results returned in that specific order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [sort based script](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) something like (not tested):

```
doc['account_level_id'].value == "5" ? 3 : doc['account_level_id'].value == "4" ? 5 : doc['account_level_id'].value == "3" ? 4 : doc['account_level_id'].value == "2" ? 2 : 1;
```

Or if possible you could create another field `sort_level` that maps `account_level_id` to sensible values that you can sort on.

```
{  
    "_index":"businesses",
    "_type":"business",
    "_id":"1",
    "_version":1,
    "found":true,
    "_source":{  
        "business":{  
            "account_level_id":"4",
            "business_city":"Abington",
            "business_country":"United States of America",
            "sort_level": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort in DESC you can create function that maps integers and sort using it.
DESC should sort them like (5 4 3 2 1), 5 replaced by 4, 4 replaced by 3, 3 replaced by 5.

```
int map_to(int x){
   switch(x){
          case 1: case 2: return x; 
          case 3: return 4;
          case 4: return 5;
          case 5: return 3;
   }  
}
```

and use it for your sorting algorithm (so when sorting algorithm has to compare x vs y it should compare map_to(x) vs map_to(y) , and this will make 4 comes before 3 and 5 as you want.

Comment: This would work after I get the results, but I need to sort before I get the results, due to pagination.